# How to calculate Trailing Moving Sums going up vertically in a table?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, sum, financial

I have the following *table*: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTHIZ.png)

Columns 'L' and 'U' if the table consist of cells that contain object names that correspond to the headers in columns 4-281. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChwN6.png)

**Goal: For every date verify what objects are in 'L' (respectively 'U') and sum the aggregate of those objects' 4-point trailing moving sum and its standard deviation (going up in the table!) and store it in a new variable, e.g. LSum and LStd for 'L' as well as USum and UStd for 'U'. For dates with insufficient values, e.g. 15-Jul-2016 with only 3 instead of 4 time steps ahead, return *NaN*'s.**

How I would start:

```
for row=1:size(ABC,1)
    row_values = ABC{row,:}; 
    row_values = row_values(4:end);
% How to make the loop for columns L and U where there are multiple objects in one cell?
% How can I use 'movsum' and 'movstd' here to calculate values vertically going up?
end;
```

**Thanks a lot for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the functions `cell2mat` and `cellfun` to achieve your goal.

With these functions you can:

1. Convert your cell matrix to a double matrix in order to perform (`cell2mat`)
2. Perform a certain operation on all cell elements (`cellfun`)

Comment: thanks Wouter. Can you be more precise, please? Especially how I can use those formulas in the context of required loops (see above).